# Creating a dictionary of anagrams

Tags: c#, performance, parsing

I have a dictionary with about 4.2 millions of lines, each line contains a word (+some trash data I don't need) or whitespace. I need to convert this into a dictionary of anagrams (words that can be created from another words by changing positions of letters).

So far I came up with this solution:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<wordModel> listAnagram = new List<wordModel>();
        string path = "D:\\words1.txt";
        string outputPath = "D:\\anagrams.txt";

        long count = 0;
        long total = 4302072;

        List<char> wordChars = new List<char>();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        wordModel anagram = null;

        using (FileStream fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line.Trim())) continue;
                string word = line.Split('|')[0].Trim();

                Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
                Console.Write($"{++count}/{total}");

                wordChars.Clear();
                foreach (char c in word) { wordChars.Add(c); }
                wordChars.Sort();

                sb.Clear();
                foreach (char c in wordChars)
                {
                    sb.Append(c);
                }

                string wordLetters = sb.ToString();

                anagram = listAnagram.FirstOrDefault(x => x.length == wordLetters.Length && x.letters.Equals(wordLetters));
                if (anagram == null)
                {
                    listAnagram.Add(new wordModel()
                    {
                        letters = wordLetters,
                        listAnagram = new List<string>() { word },
                        length = wordLetters.Length
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!anagram.listAnagram.Any(x => x.Equals(word)))
                    {
                        anagram.listAnagram.Add(word);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\n\nDone reading...");
        listAnagram.OrderBy(x => x.listAnagram.Count);

        using (FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(outputPath))
        using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
        using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(bs))
        {
            total = listAnagram.Count;
            count = 0;
            foreach (wordModel word in listAnagram)
            {
                sr.WriteLine($"({word.listAnagram.Count}) {string.Join(", ", word.listAnagram)}");

                Console.SetCursorPosition(5, 0);
                Console.Write($"{++count}/{total}");
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nDone");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public class wordModel
    {
        public int length { get; set; }
        public string letters { get; set; }
        public List<string> listAnagram { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Performance-wise it's pretty slow (worked through ~300k lines in 10 minutes, slows down later, worked through 2.2M lines in 8 hours). What can I do to make it run faster?

Small example of data I'm working with:

```
лань | сущ одуш ед жен им | 8831
  лани | сущ одуш ед жен род | 8832
  лани | сущ одуш ед жен дат | 8833
  лань | сущ одуш ед жен вин | 8834
  ланью | сущ одуш ед жен тв | 8835
  лани | сущ одуш ед жен пр | 8836
лани | сущ одуш мн им | 1430139
  ланей | сущ одуш мн род | 1430140
  ланям | сущ одуш мн дат | 1430141
  ланей | сущ одуш мн вин | 1430142
  ланями | сущ одуш мн тв | 1430143
  ланях | сущ одуш мн пр | 1430144

лаосец | сущ одуш ед муж им | 1212979
  лаосца | сущ одуш ед муж род | 1212980
  лаосцу | сущ одуш ед муж дат | 1212981
  лаосца | сущ одуш ед муж вин | 1212982
  лаосцем | сущ одуш ед муж тв | 1212983
  лаосце | сущ одуш ед муж пр | 1212984
лаосцы | сущ одуш мн им | 1305804
  лаосцев | сущ одуш мн род | 1305805
  лаосцам | сущ одуш мн дат | 1305806
  лаосцев | сущ одуш мн вин | 1305807
  лаосцами | сущ одуш мн тв | 1305808
  лаосцах | сущ одуш мн пр | 1305809

лаоска | сущ одуш ед жен им | 150572
  лаоски | сущ одуш ед жен род | 345790
  лаоске | сущ одуш ед жен дат | 345791
  лаоску | сущ одуш ед жен вин | 345792
  лаоскою | сущ одуш ед жен тв | 345795
  лаоской | сущ одуш ед жен тв | 345793
  лаоске | сущ одуш ед жен пр | 345794
лаоски | сущ одуш мн им | 1430145
  лаосок | сущ одуш мн род | 1430146
  лаоскам | сущ одуш мн дат | 1430147
  лаосок | сущ одуш мн вин | 1430148
  лаосками | сущ одуш мн тв | 1430149
  лаосках | сущ одуш мн пр | 1430150

лаосский | прл ед муж им | 107469
  лаосского | прл ед муж род | 498587
  лаосскому | прл ед муж дат | 498588
  лаосского | прл ед муж вин одуш | 498592
  лаосский | прл ед муж вин неод | 498589
  лаосским | прл ед муж тв | 498590
  лаосском | прл ед муж пр | 498591
лаосская | прл ед жен им | 684497
  лаосской | прл ед жен род | 684498
  лаосской | прл ед жен дат | 684499
  лаосскую | прл ед жен вин | 684500
  лаосскою | прл ед жен тв | 684503
  лаосской | прл ед жен тв | 684501
  лаосской | прл ед жен пр | 684502
лаосское | прл ед ср им | 866230
  лаосского | прл ед ср род | 866231
  лаосскому | прл ед ср дат | 866232
  лаосское | прл ед ср вин | 866233
  лаосским | прл ед ср тв | 866234
  лаосском | прл ед ср пр | 866235
лаосские | прл мн им | 1083295
  лаосских | прл мн род | 1083296
  лаосским | прл мн дат | 1083297
  лаосские | прл мн вин неод | 1083298
  лаосских | прл мн вин одуш | 1083301
  лаосскими | прл мн тв | 1083299
  лаосских | прл мн пр | 1083300
```

**Solved**:
Thanks to paparazzo for idea with dictionaries. Here is my final version, it works much faster (completed in ~1.5 minutes).

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, List<string>>> dicAnagram = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, List<string>>>();

        string path = "D:\\words1.txt";
        string outputPath = "D:\\anagrams.txt";

        long count = 0;
        long total = 4302072;

        using (FileStream fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs))
        {
            string word;
            while ((word = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(word.Trim())) continue;
                word = word.Split('|')[0].Trim();

                Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
                Console.Write($"{++count}/{total}");

                byte[] wordContent = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(word);
                Array.Sort(wordContent);
                string key = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(wordContent);

                if (!dicAnagram.ContainsKey(key.Length)) { dicAnagram.Add(key.Length, new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()); }

                Dictionary<string, List<string>> dicByLength = dicAnagram[key.Length];

                if (!dicByLength.ContainsKey(key)) { dicByLength.Add(key, new List<string>()); }
                if (!dicByLength[key].Any(x => x.Equals(word)))
                {
                    dicByLength[key].Add(word);
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\n\nDone reading...");

        using (FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(outputPath))
        using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
        using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(bs))
        {
            foreach (Dictionary<string, List<string>> dic in dicAnagram.Values)
            {
                total = dic.Values.Count;
                count = 0;
                foreach (List<string> words in dic.Values)
                {
                    sr.WriteLine($"({words.Count}) {string.Join(", ", words)}");

                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 5);
                    Console.Write($"{++count}/{total}");
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nDone");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add a couple of lines of sample data so that we can better visualize what you are dealing with?

Comment: You are not writing to a dictionary.   Don't write to console every line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A big problem is you are not writing to Dictionary.  You are storing in a List.

```
List<wordModel> listAnagram = new List<wordModel>();
```

This is going to be slow - O(n).  No reason to search on Length.

```
anagram = listAnagram.FirstOrDefault(x => x.length == wordLetters.Length && x.letters.Equals(wordLetters));
```

Below will be be O(1).

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> DicAnagram = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>(); 

List<string> words = DicAnagram[wordLetters];
```

Don't write to the console every line.

```
Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
Console.Write($"{++count}/{total}");
```

Write out like every 1000 lines.

If this has several '|' then you would read char by char to stop at the first.

```
string word = line.Split('|')[0].Trim();
```

Comment: +1, but I'm one of those people who objects to HashTables being assumed `O(1)`; however, string hashes are one thing that a lot of work has gone into, so hopefully it will perform as such.